# Cross-referencing MySQL entries

Tags: php, mysql

This is the first time I've used this place, so forgive me if I'm being completely stupid here.

Basically, I'm coding a system where User A signs an institution up to the service, receiving a verification code for members of that institution, and then User B, part of that institution, enters the unique verification code to register.

The code for signing up User A works - it assigns a unique auto-incrementing ID (sid, or uid in the database) and a random verification code (verification) - and I am satisfied with it (aside from security concerns, but I need to learn how to deal with those).

My problem is that whenever anyone tries to sign up as a User B, and use the verification code, the system rejects it, and says that the verification code does not match the one under that particular sid. I have a feeling it's to do with the code I am using to look up the verification id, but I don't know where I'm going wrong.

The current code:

```
$getsid = mysql_query(
"SELECT *
FROM schools
WHERE uid='$sid'");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($getsid)) {
    $origver = $row['verification'];
    }

if ($pwd != $conf) {
        header('Location: register.php?error=1');
    }
elseif ($ver != $origver) {
    header('Location: register.php?error=2');
    }
else {
```

Just for further information, `$ver` is the verification number entered by User B, which is meant to match with `$origver`.

Comment: **Heads up!** Future versions of PHP are *deprecating and removing* the `mysql_` family of functions. Now would be a great time to [switch to PDO](http://php.net/book.pdo) or [mysqli](http://php.net/book.mysqli).

Comment: Are you sure that only one value is being returned from your query? Is it possible that your while loop is continuing past where you think it is ending up on a different value? Why not break out when you have the correct value?

Comment: …or add a `LIMIT`-clause to the SQL query.

Comment: This is what I mean by me being a novice, I have no idea how to do either :P

Comment: What is `$pwd` and `$conf` supposed to be?

Comment: They're variables entered in the form too. Password and password confirmation, namely.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you must add some debug statements, in order to see what's going on

```
var_dump($sid);
$getsid = mysql_query(
"SELECT *
FROM schools
WHERE uid='$sid'");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($getsid)) {
    var_dump($row);
    $origver = $row['verification'];
}

var_dump($pwd, $conf);
if ($pwd != $conf) {
        header('Location: register.php?error=1');
```